# Starting an Oracle DB using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm starting an oracle DB in docker (on OS **Windows 10**) with the following command:

```
docker run -d --env-file C:\(...)\ora_db_env.dat -p 9445:1521 --name oracle-std --shm-size="8g" container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard
```

**Works fine**. Now I want to do the same using docker compose. https://www.composerize.com/ gives me the following docker-compose.yml file, so it is missing the informations for 'shm-size' and all from my 'ora_db_env.dat', (see below):

```
    version: '3.3'
    services:
        oracle-std-service:
            ports:
                - '9445:1521'
            container_name: oracle-std-service-container
            image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard

(...other services...)
```

Contents of 'ora_db_env.dat':

```
DB_SID=OraDoc
DB_PASSWD=MyPasswd123
DB_DOMAIN=my.domain.com
DB_BUNDLE=basic
```

I tried including those missing informations...

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    oracle-std-service:
        container_name: oracle-std-service-container
        ports:
            - '9445:1521'
        image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard
        environment:
            shm-size: 8g
            DB_SID: OraDoc
            DB_PASSWD: MyPasswd123
            DB_DOMAIN: my.domain.com
            DB_BUNDLE: basic
```

...but I only get the following output:

```
config DB failed, please check log /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log for details
```

Not knowing (also after googling it) where to find this file in Windows, I don't know what to do.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Comment: this location /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log is present inside the container. Use docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/sh command and login to cli mode of container and view it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be sure 100% about this, due to lack of logs, but this can be failing due to **shm-size** configuration
SHM_SIZE is a docker config and so should be declared at service level and not as environment.
**Like**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    oracle-std-service:
        shm_size: 8g
        container_name: oracle-std-service-container
        ports:
            - '9445:1521'
        image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard
```

See [SHM_SIZE in docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#shm_size)

**Log location** is inside the container, you can use docker exec to access it if the container is still running, find its name by using `docker ps -a`

```
docker exec --it <oracle container name> bash
```

And if it is stopped already then you will have to start it and access using `exec`

Answer (score 1):

Yes...being able to see the logs with help from Arun Sa i confirm that the problem was the shm_size parameter being at the wrong position in docker-compose.yml. Problem solved, tahnk you very much:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    oracle-std-service:
        shm_size: '8gb'
        container_name: oracle-std-service-container
        ports:
            - '9445:1521'
        image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard
        environment:            
            DB_SID: OraDoc
            DB_PASSWD: MyPasswd123
            DB_DOMAIN: my.domain.com
            DB_BUNDLE: basic
```